# Задача - вывести сумму нечётных элементов. Почему не учитывает отрицательные значения? Прошу помочь

Tags: c#, массивы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp66
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the dimension of array: ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] A = new int[a];

            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
                A[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                if (A[i] % 2 == 1)
                {
                    sum += A[i];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of all no paired elements of array - {0}", sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "непарные" - это нечетные? "минусовые" - это отрицательные? Добавьте пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Пример выполнения программы:
   Введите 1-й элемент массива: 15
   Введите 2-й элемент массива: 2
   Введите 3-й элемент массива: 4
   Введите 4-й элемент массива: -7
   Введите 5-й элемент массива: 9
   Введите 6-й элемент массива: 24
   -------------------------------------------------- -----------
  Массив: 15 2 4 -7 9 24
  Сумма нечетных элементов массива: 17

Comment: Проверьте, чему равно `A[i] % 2` для отрицательного `A[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что нужно брать `A[i]` по модулю. Т.к. результат может быть не 1 а -1